# Cannot run Connect-AzureAD on Mac powershell

Tags: macos, powershell

I ran the following commands as per some other posts:

```
Install-Module -Name AzureAD  
Import-Module AzureAD -UseWindowsPowerShell
```

When I try to execute `Connect-AzureAD`, the standard error comes up:

```
Connect-AzureAd: The term 'Connect-AzureAd' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
```

Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Any ideas on how to get Connect-AzureAD to work on powershell for Mac?

Comment: this >>> `-UseWindowsPowerShell` <<< seems to day that you expect windows powershell to be available on MacOS. why do you expect that?

Answer (score 4):

"AzureAD" and "AzureADPReview" modules are only supported with Windows PowerShell 5.1 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0).

if you want to access Azure AD using PowerShell 7 (e.g. from MacOS), you need to use different modules:

- "Az" modules
- "Microsoft.Graph.*" modules (e.g. "Microsoft.Graph.Users", "Microsoft.Graph.Groups")

ref:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/azure/install-az-ps
- https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/powershell/installation